# Xcode 6 Beta - Apple Mach-O Linker error

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, swift, xcode6-beta6

After updating to the recently released beta 6 of Xcode 6, my swift project fails to build due to the following errors.

[image: Xcode 6 Beta 6 issue]

Looking at previous questions on this issue, propose checking the build architecture is set to support arm which mine project includes already (arm64, armv7s, armv7).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

First, make sure you have the most recent beta installed. Afterwards delete your DerivedData folder ( ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData ). This should allow you to compile again in the latest beta.

Edit: This appears to hold  true for the newest beta version of the Xcode as well

Comment: I fixed Xcode not building my project with this one weird trick!

Comment: I confirm that this issue still exists in Xcode 6 Beta 7.

Comment: I got the same issue with Beta 7, but removing the DerivedData fixed it. I only deleted the DerivedData for the project I was working on, not all my other projects. Building happily now

Answer (score 3):

From what I hear, so far Xcode 6 Beta 6 is broken. You should uninstall and rollback to Beta 5.

Edit: 
Apparently, a new version is already out, just reinstall beta 6

http://9to5mac.com/2014/08/18/apple-re-releases-xcode-6-beta-6-solves-issues-discovered-by-developers-in-new-build/

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you install the latest Xcode Beta 6 version. If you check Xcode->About Xcode, you should see: `Version 6.0 (6A280e)`

Comment: Thanks, yeap got `6A280e`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I reinstalled Xcode. then it fixed the problem.
In my case it happened because of deleting a imported framework(move to trash) which is inside my project navigator. I think Xcode delete the whole framework when we delete(move to trash) imported framework from our project navigator.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you haven't done any unnecessary imports example importing an .h file when you needed .m

Comment: I suppose, you wanted to say, "Make sure you haven't done any unnecessary imports example importing an .m file when you needed .h" ..?